# dlang how to convert and trim a char[] into a string?

Tags: string, d

I am trying to convert a buffer to string but apparently there is this space that I cannot remove
How should I strip this space and convert a char[] into an string container

```
string getClass(HWND hwnd=NULL){
    char[100] str;
    GetClassNameA(hwnd, str.ptr, str.length);
    writeln(str.dup.strip,'"'); //nothing is stripped, str is printed as 100 characters
    writeln(str[99]=='\0'); //false
    writeln(str[99]==' '); //false
    writeln(str.dup[99]=='\0'); //false
    writeln(str.dup[99]==' '); //false
    writeln(str.dup.strip[99]=='\0'); //false
    writeln(str.dup.strip[99]==' '); //false
    return to!string(str).strip; //same nothing is stripped
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to slice the buffer with the correct length. `GetClassName` returns the length of the string so do something like

```
char[100] buffer;
auto recv = GetClassNameA(hwnd, buffer.ptr, buffer.length);
if(recv == 0) throw new Exception("failed");
char[] str = buffer[0 .. recv];
// now you can work with str
```

Comment: You are right, thank you. It's a luck that GetClassName returns the length.

Comment: Not luck, that's by design for exactly uses like this.

Comment: If it didn't, you could also scan the string for the zero terminator (`strlen` function) and slice with that btw.

Comment: It does, you just ass it the `.ptr`. `char[] str = fromStringz(buffer.ptr);` works just as well (its implementation is just strlen but packaged nicer: `return cString ? cString[0 .. strlen(cString)] : null;`). You wouldn't want to pass it the static array though because then you'd get a pointer to a temporary that outlives its parent.